# How to get the node id before saving the node in drupal 6?

Tags: 6, nodes, hooks

I have created a content type called 'inquiry.'  I am using the rules module to send an email after submitting an inquiry.  My requirement is to get the node id before it is saved.  I need to generate a link from that node id so the inquiry handler can view the inquiry by clicking on that link.

Comment: You can't get the node id of a new node *before* the node is saved. The node is generated in MySQL when the node is saved. As you use rules, just switch the event from presave to insert/update.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_nodeapi presave option to get node content before saving the node.

**Example :**

```
function MODULENAME_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'presave':
      print $node->nid;
      exit;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: i have not created custom module , so what should i write in place of MODULENAME ..???

Comment: Karthi would reply "any name you want". But make sure that it's any string that can be used as a function name. But usually we use a lowercase short name for the module. it should be used in other hooks, in .info file name and event better in the module's folder name.

Comment: This will not work ofr newly created nodes. On node creation $node->nid will not be set until the node is actually saved in the database. This will only works when an existing node is updated.